# Multer gives unexpetcted end of form error

Tags: node.js, image, file-upload, nodejs-server

The file is being send to the nodejs server, but the upload.single gives an unexpected end of form error. How do i fix this?

```
const upload = multer({ dest: "../../uploaded_images" });    
router.patch("/profile", upload.single("profileImage"), (req, res) => {   
    console.log(req.files) // This shows that there is a file named profileImage, I can see that when I remove the upload.single("profileImage")
    res.send("")
})
```

the file structure:

[image]

Comment: did you get solution?

Comment: This is the solution I used and it worked for me; [Solution to "unexpetcted end of form" error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72887603/how-to-solve-multer-error-unexpected-end-of-form)

Answer (score 1):

It seems to be a bug in Multer itself. I solved by downgrading Multer to 1.4.3.

See https://github.com/expressjs/multer/issues/1144

Comment: The bug is seemingly still not fixed and the problem with 1.4.3 is to my understanding that there is an existing security defect.