# Unexpected end of form error when using Multer

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, multer

I'm trying to upload an image (jpg/jpeg/png) from the browser to NodeJS. I have read through several tutorials and many posts on forums but very few seem to have this specific issue.

- I've made sure to match the name provided to multer (`upload.single('upload')`) with the formData key (`formData.append('upload', selectedFile, selectedFile.name)`)
- I tried using headers originally, but later read that I should exclude them.
- I tried submitting through a `<form action="/upload" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">` but still got the same error.

I have found this similar question with only one answer which isn't clear
[Multer gives unexpetcted end of form error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72485930/multer-gives-unexpetcted-end-of-form-error) and this question [Unexpected end of form at Multipart._final](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72515125/unexpected-end-of-form-at-multipart-final) which has no answers.
Every other question seems to be about an 'Unexpected field' or 'Unexpected end of multipart data' error which - judging from the solutions - is irrelevant here.

Below is my code...

**Browser:**

```
<body>
  <input type="file" id="file_uploader" name="upload" />
  <button onclick="uploadImage()" class="btn-default">SUBMIT</button>
  
  <!-- OTHER STUFF -->

</body>
<script>
  let selectedFile;
  let uploadData = new FormData();
    
  const fileInput = document.getElementById('file_uploader');
  fileInput.onchange = () => {
    selectedFile = fileInput.files[0];
    uploadData.append('upload', selectedFile, selectedFile.name);
  }

  function uploadImage(){
    fetch('/upload', {
      method: 'POST',
      body: uploadData
    }) 
    .then((response) => {
      console.log(response);
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.error('Error: ', error);
    });
  }
</script>
```

**NodeJS**

```
let express = require('express');
const multer = require('multer');

//multer options
const upload = multer({
  dest: './upload/',
  limits: {
    fileSize: 1000000,
  }
})

const app = express();

app.post('/upload', upload.single('upload'), (req, res) => {
  res.send();
}, (error, req, res, next) => {
  console.log(error.message);
})

exports.app = functions.https.onRequest(app);
```

...And here is the error log, if it helps:

```
Error: Unexpected end of form
>      at Multipart._final (C:\Users\p\Downloads\MyInvestmentHub\functions\node_modules\busboy\lib\types\multipart.js:588:17)
>      at callFinal (node:internal/streams/writable:694:27)
>      at prefinish (node:internal/streams/writable:723:7)
>      at finishMaybe (node:internal/streams/writable:733:5)
>      at Multipart.Writable.end (node:internal/streams/writable:631:5)
>      at onend (node:internal/streams/readable:693:10)
>      at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:78:11)
```

I haven't posted many questions as of yet, so I apologise if I'm missing something or the format is off. Let me know and I will make appropriate edits.

Thanks.

Comment: whats @Updog (see what i did there) anyways, i got this exact same error, in my code i was saying if there was an error, console log the err and it was returning a simplified message, but i removed the console log and it revealed a larger issue, which was a directory direction, i.e. `this directory doesnt exist` make sure that the directory your pointing to actually exists, if it doesnt, make sure you create it.

Comment: Hey what's up, lol. I've messed around with the directory already and noticed that, if there isn't a directory in the location I specified, it creates one anyway! It's definitely worth having another look at though, since I'm out of options.

Comment: Hi , are you able to find the solution? I am stuck in the issue for sometime.

Comment: @pratim No sorry, I did not. I eventually moved onto other tasks. I will come back to it. I haven't tried the suggestion by SocalWudan yet, it may work. Good luck! report back here if you solve it :D

Comment: If the user first selects one file, then changes their mind and selects another, `uploadData.append` is executed for both files. Not sure if this is related to your problem, but it's not what you want. Move the `let uploadData = new FormData();` inside the `fileUpload.onchange` function.

Comment: @HeikoTheißen Hi, no it is not related to my problem but I appreciate it anyway. I would not have noticed that. Thanks!

Answer (score 16):

I also got the exact same error.

Before using multer I had installed `express-fileupload`. When I unistalled it using the command `npm uninstall express-fileupload` I could get rid of the error.

And if it is the same case with you don't forget to delete the commands you already added for `express-fileupload` module. (like requiring fileupload)

Comment: This was my issue too, Thanks!

Answer (score 15):

I had this problem using multer with next js api. What worked for me is, I exported a config that sets bodyParser to false like so;

```
export const config = {
  api: {
    bodyParser: false
  }
}
```

Comment: For Next.js, This is the right answer.

Comment: For others, to be clear, this `export` is in the API route file. https://nextjs.org/docs/api-routes/request-helpers

Should mark as correct answer.

Comment: Could you have a look at this please? I'm using bodyParser in my app so there might be a collision there? It's needed for other routes but should I disable it for routes that use multer? Here is the full issue? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76064309/unexpected-end-of-form-at-callfinal-error

Answer (score 5):

Hi there I ran into the same issue for me was the lack of a `bodyParser` middleware that allows our requests files to parsed into `Buffers`.

I was able to resolve the problem like so in express:

```js
   var bodyParser = require('body-parser')

bodyParser.json([options])
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, were those the only two lines you required? What options did you use?

Comment: I used no options just invoked the function . and yes those were the lines i required , is your issue resolved ?

Comment: sorry, maybe I'm being stupid but it looks like you have passed [options] to the bodyParser.json(). If I try to run the server it crashes because options hasn't been defined.
In any case, I looked at the documentation and the default options should be enough, but I am still getting the same error

Comment: Sorry , i don't receive message notifications . would you mind trying https://github.com/mscdex/connect-busboy instead of multer ? 

And how are you testing that endPoint ? are you naming the upload field to "upload" . if you're testing with postman you should set "upload" as the field name of your file input .

Comment: I have this on my server.js but I get the same issue.

Answer (score 3):

In my case, the cause was other middleware. Check for other middleware running before multer. For me, the issue was express-openapi-validator middleware. Once I removed that middleware, it worked as expected.

Comment: Thanks, I had the same issue! Amazing, just a few days apart lol.

Answer (score 2):

Try downgrading Multer to 1.4.3. It worked for me.

See https://github.com/expressjs/multer/issues/1144

Comment: This is not a solution anymore unfortunately: multer@1.4.3 because Multer 1.x is affected by CVE-2022-24434.

Comment: This Worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

i solved the prob by removing express fileuplod

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

Using `body-parser` package worked for me:

```
const bodyParser = require('body-parser')
// ...
app.use(bodyParser()) // support encoded bodies
```

My upload single file route:

```
const multer = require('multer')
const express = require('express')
const router = express()
const path = require('path') // node built-in path package

// needs "app.use(bodyParser())" middleware to work

const storage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: function (req, file, cb) {
        cb(null, process.cwd() + '/public/')
    },
    filename: function (req, file, cb) {
        // generate the public name, removing problematic characters
        const originalName = encodeURIComponent(path.parse(file.originalname).name).replace(/[^a-zA-Z0-9]/g, '')
        const timestamp = Date.now()
        const extension = path.extname(file.originalname).toLowerCase()
        cb(null, originalName + '_' + timestamp + extension)
    }
})

const upload = multer({
    storage: storage,
    limits: { fileSize: 1 * 1024 * 1024 }, // 1 Mb
    fileFilter: (req, file, callback) => {
        const acceptableExtensions = ['png', 'jpg', 'jpeg', 'jpg']
        if (!(acceptableExtensions.some(extension => 
            path.extname(file.originalname).toLowerCase() === `.${extension}`)
        )) {
            return callback(new Error(`Extension not allowed, accepted extensions are ${acceptableExtensions.join(',')}`))
        }
        callback(null, true)
    }
})

router.post('/api/upload/single', upload.single('file'), (req, res) => {
    res.status(200).json(req.file)
})

module.exports = {
    uploadRouter: router
}
```

Comment: deprecated (2024)

Answer (score 1):

in my frontend or client-side removing the headers in my request. And make sure your inputs are as a formData.

For example:

```
let formData = new FormData();
formData.append("fileName", file);

const res = await fetch("/api/create-card", {
      method: "POST",
      body: formData,
 })
```

This worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

In my case I was using the multer middleware twice, that was causing the error. For anyone who can't find a solution check if you made the same mistake.

Comment: Was the case for me too!

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, however I solved the issue by replacing:

```
app.use(express.urlencoded(extended:false))
```

With:

```
const bodyParser = require("body-parser")

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded(extended:false))
```

Comment: app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended:false})); //You forgot the { }

Answer (score 0):

I think this is may causes by the responsed end,so in your continuous Middleware,you can do upload file at last.
i do this resolve problems.

```js
const upload = multer({
  dest: "./uploads",
});
app.use(upload.any());
app.post(
  "/upload",
  (req, res, next) => {
    res.end("文件上传成功");
  },
  upload.single("fileKey")
);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think, the problem is in the `express` and `body-parser` module, I just eliminated it

```
app.use(bodyParser.text({ type: '/' }));
```

and it works!

Answer (score 0):

In my case replacing the

```
body: uploadData
```

to

```
body: uploadData.getBuffer().toString("utf8")
```

solved the issue.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem when I moved the backend **from monolithic to microservices** because I had to use a proxy. I was using `proxy('users:90')` from the `require('express-http-proxy')` library and it constantly gave me exactly this error.
I was only able to get it working with the
`createProxyMiddleware(...)` , from the `require('http-proxy-middleware')` library.

In the gateway microservice, I directed the routes as follows:

```
const proxy =  require('express-http-proxy');
app.use("/users",  proxy('users:80'));
```

The problem was that this function didn't fill in the headers properly. Since in this microservice I had to upload files and also common routes with JSON output, I created the following middleware function:

```
app.use('/users', createProxyMiddleware({ // this is necessary for handle fileUpload
      target: `http://users:80`,
      changeOrigin: true,
      pathRewrite: {
        '^/users': '',
      },
      onProxyReq: (proxyReq: any, req: any, res: any) => {
        const contentType = req.headers['content-type']; // get content type of request
        if (req.body && typeof contentType !== 'undefined' && !contentType.includes('multipart/form-data')) {  // verify if isn't Post with upload files
          const bodyData = JSON.stringify(req.body);
          proxyReq.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
          proxyReq.setHeader('Content-Length', Buffer.byteLength(bodyData));
          proxyReq.write(bodyData);
        }
      },
      onError: (err: any, req: any, res: any) => {
        console.error('Proxy error:', err);
        res.status(500).send('Proxy error');
      },
    }));
```

The `onProxyReq` function was necessary specify because after these change, fileupload works and the normal api routes don't.
After adding this middleware, **works normally**.

Answer (score -1):

try using these it work

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
const path = require('path')
const multer = require('multer')

var filestorageEngine = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: (req, file, cb) => {
        cb(null,'./uploads')
    },
    filename:(req,file, cb) => {
        cb(null,"[maues]-" + file.originalname)
    }
})

var upload = multer({
    storage:filestorageEngine
})

app.post('/file', upload.array('file', 3),(req, res) => {
   console.log(req.file)
    res.send("file uploaded successfully")
})

app.listen(5000, ()=> {
    console.log("server running")
})
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).