# Multer Error: Unexpected end of form at Multipart._final

Tags: node.js, reactjs, firebase, multer

I am using the multer package to handle uploading files to a google cloud bucket. Initially, my multer package was working correctly but once I migrated to firebase I found that all my attempts to upload files were not resolving.

After running `firebase functions:log` I found I was receiving the message `Error: Unexpected end of form at Multipart._final` I'm not totally sure why this error may be occurring especially since it was previously working.

This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72544409/unexpected-end-of-form-error-when-using-multer) seems to have the same issue however there don't seem to be any answers which help me. If possible I would like to know what the error message itself means as well.

Below is my code for invoking my multer function

```
 const sendFile = () =>{
        if(acceptedFiles.length > 0){
            for(let i = 0; i < acceptedFiles.length; i++){
              let file = acceptedFiles[i]
      
              let blob = file.slice(0,file.size)
              let newFile = new File([blob], file.name, {type: "text/plain"});
      
              let formData = new FormData();
              formData.append('dataFile',newFile)
      
      
              fetch('https://somePath',{
                method: "Post",
                body: formData
              })
                .then(res => res.text())
                .then((x) => console.log(x))
                .then(() => sendDB(acceptedFiles[i],i))
            }
          }else{
            window.alert("No files have been selected to be uploaded")
          }
    }
```

Here is where I actually send my file to my google bucket

```
app.post('/uploadFile', multer.single('dataFile'),async (req,res) =>{

    console.log('made it to upload')
    try{
        if(req.file){
            console.log('file found trying to upload....')
            const blob = bucket.file(req.file.originalname);
            const blobstream = blob.createWriteStream();

            blobstream.on('finish',() => {
                res.status(200).send('Success')
            })
            blobstream.end(req.file.buffer);
        }
    }catch(error){
        res.status(500).send(error);
        console.log(error)
    }
})
```

Here is how I configured my multer and google cloud storage

```
const multer = Multer({
    storage: Multer.memoryStorage()
})

let projectId = 'someID'
let keyFilename = 'someKeyFileName'

const storage = new Storage({
    projectId,
    keyFilename
})
```

I'm more than happy to provide any additional information if it's needed.

Update:

After some more research, it seems that firebase does not support serverside file upload. Is this only when using firebase storage or will this also apply to my case where I am attempting to upload my files to a google cloud bucket? Reference to this [claim](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39848132/upload-files-to-firebase-storage-using-node-js) in case I'm incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if it's your case, because I was getting the same error, but without firebase, however in my case the problem was Multer itself. Dowgraded to 1.4.3 and it started working.

See https://github.com/expressjs/multer/issues/1144

Comment: Yes the issue is firebase does not support multer due to how firebase pre-processes requests. Therefore the solution is to use a low level library like busboy or google itself has an easier solution using a newer function called .save. However, based on the number of questions I've found on stackoverflow and the answers those questions get I would say it's poorly documented.