# Unexpected end of form while uploading a file

Tags: node.js, reactjs, redux, redux-toolkit

I am trying to create a Game, await for that action to be fulfilled, get the id of the recently created game and dispatch it with the action to upload a photo.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react'
import FormGroup from '../UI/FormGroup'
import '../../styles/components/Auth/RegisterForm.css'
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from 'react-redux';
import { createGame, uploadPhoto } from '../../slices/gameSlice';
import { fetchEmployees } from '../../slices/employeeSlice';


function GameForm() {

  const { employees: employeesList } = useSelector((state) => state.employees);
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const [games, setGames] = useState([]);
  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(fetchEmployees());
  }, [dispatch]);

    const [formData, setFormData] = useState({
        name: "",
        description: "",
        employees: [],
        hours: [
          {
            opening: "",
            closing: ""
          }
        ],
        photo:null
      });
    
      const { name, description,  hours, employees, photo } = formData;
    
      const onChange = (e) => {
        if (e.target.name === 'opening' || e.target.name === 'closing') {
          setFormData({
            ...formData,
            hours: [
              {
                ...hours[0],
                [e.target.name]: e.target.value,
              },
            ],
          });
        } else if (e.target.name === 'employees') {
          const selectedOptions = Array.from(e.target.options)
            .filter((option) => option.selected)
            .map((option) => option.value);
          setFormData({ ...formData, [e.target.name]: selectedOptions });
        } else if (e.target.name === 'photo') {
          setFormData({ ...formData, photo: e.target.files[0] }); // Update this line
        } else {
          setFormData({ ...formData, [e.target.name]: e.target.value });
        }
      };
      

      const onSubmit = async (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        console.log('Form submitted', formData)
        try {
          const gameData = {
            name,
            description,
            hours,
            employees
          };
      
          const createdGame = await dispatch(createGame(gameData)).unwrap();
          setGames([...games, createdGame]);
          await dispatch(uploadPhoto({ id: createdGame._id, file: photo })).unwrap();
        } catch (error) {
          console.log(error);
        }
      };
      
      

    const formFields = [
        {
          name: "name",
          type: "text",
          placeholder: "Name",
          label: "Name",
          value: name,
          onChange: onChange
        },
        {
          name: "description",
          type: "text",
          placeholder: "Description",
          label: "Description",
          value: description,
          onChange: onChange
        },
        {
            name: "photo",
            type: "file",
            placeholder: "Game Photo",
            label: "Game Photo",
            onChange: onChange
        },
        {
         name: "opening",
         type: "datetime-local",
         placeholder: "Opening Hour",
         label: "Opening Hour",
         value: hours[0].opening,
         onChange: onChange
        },
        {
          name: "closing",
          type: "datetime-local",
          placeholder: "Closing Hour",
          label: "Closing Hour",
          value: hours[0].closing,
          onChange: onChange
         },
         {
          name: "employees",
          type: "select",
          placeholder: "Employees",
          label: "Employees",
          value: employees,
          options: employeesList.filter(employee => employee.type === 'manager').map((employee) => ({
            value: employee._id,
            label: `${employee.name} ${employee.lastName}`,
          })),
          multiple: true,
          onChange: onChange
        },
      ]
      
      /* console.log(formData) */
      
  return (
    <div style={{display: 'flex', justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center', height: '100vh', width: '100%'}}>
      <form className='form_container' onSubmit={onSubmit} encType='multipart/form-data'>
        {formFields.map((field) => (
          <FormGroup key={field.name} {...field} multiple={field.multiple} />
        ))}
        <button type="submit">Register</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  )
}

export default GameForm
```

My form has an `encType=multipart/form-data`

And the following is my gameSlice

```
import { createSlice, createAsyncThunk } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';
import axios from 'axios';

const initialState = {
  games: [],
  isLoading: false,
};

export const createGame = createAsyncThunk(
  'games/createGame',
  async (game, { rejectWithValue }) => {
    try {
      const config = {
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        },
      };
      const body = JSON.stringify(game);
      const response = await axios.post(
        'http://localhost:5000/api/games/register',
        body,
        config
      );
      return response.data.data;
    } catch (error) {
      return rejectWithValue(error.response.data);
    }
  }
);

export const uploadPhoto = createAsyncThunk(
  'games/uploadPhoto',
  async ({ id, file }, { rejectWithValue }) => {
    try {
      const formData = new FormData();
      formData.append('file', file);

      const response = await axios.put(
        `http://localhost:5000/api/games/${id}/photo`,
        formData,
        {
          headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
          },
        }
      );

      if (!response || !response.data) {
        throw new Error('Invalid response received');
      }

      return response.data;
    } catch (error) {
      return rejectWithValue(error.response?.data || error.message);
    }
  }
);

export const getGames = createAsyncThunk(
  'games/getGames',
  async (_, { rejectWithValue }) => {
    try {
      const response = await axios.get('http://localhost:5000/api/games');
      console.log(response.data);
      return response.data.data;
    } catch (error) {
      return rejectWithValue(error.response.data);
    }
  }
);

export const gameSlice = createSlice({
  name: 'games',
  initialState,
  reducers: {},
  extraReducers: (builder) => {
    builder
      .addCase(getGames.pending, (state) => {
        state.isLoading = true;
      })
      .addCase(getGames.fulfilled, (state, action) => {
        state.isLoading = false;
        state.games = action.payload;
      })
      .addCase(getGames.rejected, (state) => {
        state.isLoading = false;
        state.games = [];
      })
      .addCase(createGame.pending, (state) => {
        state.isLoading = true;
      })
      .addCase(createGame.fulfilled, (state, action) => {
        state.isLoading = false;
        state.games.push(action.payload);
      })
      .addCase(createGame.rejected, (state) => {
        state.isLoading = false;
        state.games = [];
      })
      .addCase(uploadPhoto.pending, (state) => {
        state.isLoading = true;
      })
      .addCase(uploadPhoto.fulfilled, (state, action) => {
        state.isLoading = false;
        const game = state.games.find(
          (game) => game._id === action.payload._id
        );
        if (game) {
          game.photo = action.payload.photo;
        }
      })
      .addCase(uploadPhoto.rejected, (state) => {
        state.isLoading = false;
        state.games = [];
      });
  },
});

export const {} = gameSlice.actions;

export default gameSlice.reducer;
```

When i submit my form the createGame action is fullfilled and the game is created, but then the uploadPhoto is rejected. With an error message of `Unexpected end of form`.

This is my method in my controller:

```
// @desc   Upload photo to a game
// @route  PUT /api/games/:id/photo
// @access Private

exports.uploadPhoto = asyncHandler(async (req, res, next) => {
  const game = await Game.findById(req.params.id);

  if (!game) {
    return next(
      new ErrorResponse(`Game not found with id of ${req.params.id}`, 404)
    );
  }

  if (!req.files) {
    return next(new ErrorResponse(`Please upload a file`, 400));
  }

  const file = req.files.file;

  // Make sure the image is a photo
  if (!file.mimetype.startsWith('image')) {
    return next(new ErrorResponse(`Please upload an image file`, 400));
  }

  // Check filesize
  if (file.size > process.env.MAX_FILE_UPLOAD) {
    return next(
      new ErrorResponse(
        `Please upload an image less than ${process.env.MAX_FILE_UPLOAD}`,
        400
      )
    );
  }

  // Create custom filename
  file.name = `photo_${game._id}${path.parse(file.name).ext}`;

  file.mv(`${process.env.FILE_UPLOAD_PATH}/${file.name}`, async (err) => {
    if (err) {
      console.error(err);
      return next(new ErrorResponse(`Problem with file upload`, 500));
    }

    await Game.findByIdAndUpdate(req.params.id, { photo: file.name });

    res.status(200).json({
      success: true,
      data: file.name,
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: Are you trying to do this in Next.js application? If yes have a look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72544409/unexpected-end-of-form-error-when-using-multer

Comment: @mzparacha no. Just expressjs and reactjs