# How to solve Multer Error: Unexpected end of form?

Tags: node.js, express, upload, multer, body-parser

I found other similar questions regarding Multer, but with no answers. I'm trying to upload a file with next.js (front-end) and node.js (back-end). The data is being posted via the network tab when using dev tools.

Below is my setup:

**app.js**

```js
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');

// Get routes
const routeUser = require('./routes/user');

// Create an express server
var app = express();

// Add necessary middleware
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true })); // Support encoded bodies
app.use(bodyParser.json({
  type: ["application/x-www-form-urlencoded", "application/json"], // Support json encoded bodies
}));

// Custom routes
routeUser(app);

// Start server on port 1234
app.listen(1234, () => {
  console.log("API is running.");
});
```

**route/user.js**

```js
const multer = require('multer');

module.exports = function(app) {

  const upload = multer({
    storage: multer.diskStorage({
      destination: (req, file, cb) => {
        cb(null, "./user_photos");
      },
      filename: (req, file, cb) => {
        cb(null, file.originalname)
      }
    })
  });

  app.post('/user/update', upload.single('user_photo'), (req, res) => {

    console.log(req.body, req.file);

  });
}
```

**Form**

```js
submit(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  let form_values = new FormData(event.target);
  fetch(this.props.env.api + "/user/update", {
    method: 'post',
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data; boundary=MyBoundary',
    },
    body: form_values
  }).then((response) => {
    return response.json();
  }).then((response) => {
    console.log(response);
  });
}

------

<form onSubmit={this.submit}>
  <input type="file" name="user_photo"/>
  <button type="submit">Upload</button>
</form>
```

I've tried several tutorials, I'm setting it up according to the docs, yet I keep getting the following error:

```
Error: Unexpected end of form
    at Multipart._final (...\node_modules\busboy\lib\types\multipart.js:588:17)
```

If I remove `multipart/form-data` as `Content-Type`, the form submits with no problem, but with no file. My guess it has something to do with the way the `formData` object is being received.

Comment: I think it got something to do with the content-type boundary propertie, maybe this thread could help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3508338/what-is-the-boundary-in-multipart-form-data

Comment: @SReca, Did you find any solution?

Comment: @JaynaTanawala sorry for the late reply. I put this project on the back burner and recently picked it up again. I've currently have a different custom setup and no longer using Multer. But I believe bodyParser may have been the cause of my issues when used globally.

Answer (score 3):

Hey [@SReca](https://stackoverflow.com/users/543495/sreca), just faced this issue today and hope I can help you out here and anybody else reading this.

### Resolving `Unexpected end of form`

Regarding the original issue about `Unexpected end of form`, you are correct in removing the `Content-Type` as a solution. This is because sending `FormData()` with regular Fetch or XMLHttpRequest will automatically have the header set by the Browser. The Browser will also attach the `boundary` needed in all `multipart/form-data` requests in order indicate when a form starts and ends. More details can be found on MDN's docs about [Using FormData Objects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/Using_FormData_Objects#:%7E:text=the%20open()%20call.-,Warning,-%3A%20When%20using)... there's a warning about explicitly setting `Content-Type`.

### Potential fix for missing file

Now, about the missing file, it's possible that it has an incorrect reference to the path you're expecting. I am not using `diskStorage`, but I am using regular `dest` option to save my file and had the same problem (wanted to save images to `./assets/images`). **What worked for me was to supply the complete directory path**. Maybe changing your callback function in the destination property to

```js
// Assuming the the path module is 'required' or 'imported' beforehand
cb(null, path.resolve(__dirname, '<path-to-desired-folder>'));
```

will solve the issue. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 3):

In my case the problem magically went away by downgrading Multer to 1.4.3.

See https://github.com/expressjs/multer/issues/1144

Comment: in my case too! I'm using typescript so I dwograde both, multer and @types/multer

Answer (score 0):

What caused this too me was because I was using multiple middleware on the same route, I was using global middleware and then applied another middleware in sub route. so this caused conflits.